# Camel mock endpoint for pollEnrich

Tags: mocking, apache-camel, endpoint

I tried to mock endpoint for **pollEnrich** but had no success. Mocking with adviceWith works fine for `.to("")`  and `.enrich("")`, but for pollEnrich I faced error:  
*org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8983*
I can't understand why `adviceWith` doesn't fit to `pollEnrich`
This is code for mocking:

```
public class PollEnricherRefTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    public class SampleMockRoute extends RouteBuilder {

        public void configure() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("configure");
            from("direct:sampleInput")
                    .log("Received Message is ${body} and Headers are ${headers}")
                    //.to("http4://localhost:8983/test")
                    .pollEnrich("http4://localhost:8983/test", (exchange1, exchange2) -> {
                        return exchange1;
                    })
                    .log("after enrich ${body} ")
                    .to("mock:output");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeAll() throws Exception {
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder mockHttp4 = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint("http4://localhost:8983/test")
                        .log("call MOCK HTTP").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint();

            }
        };
        context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new SampleMockRoute());
        context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, mockHttp4);
        template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleMockTest() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            context.start();
            String expected = "Hello";
            MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:output");
            mock.expectedBodiesReceived(expected);
            String input = "Hello";
            template.sendBody("direct:sampleInput", input);
            mock.assertIsSatisfied();
            context.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace pollEnrich with weaveBy...
there are various variants *weaveByType*, *weaveById* etc.

In case you use *weaveByType* and you have multiple PollEnrich in your route, you can select then with *selectFirst()*, *selectLast()* etc.

Replace can be done by another endpoint e.g. mock endpoint, but for test purposes I find it convinient to use processor and directly set desired exchange content, or keep it unchanged if needed.

Below code example for camel 3.5

```java
    ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
        RouteReifier.adviceWith(mcc.getRouteDefinition("IdOfMyRoute"), mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                weaveByType(PollEnrichDefinition.class).selectFirst().replace().processor((exchange) -> {

});
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly try using weavyByType within configure(). The only problem is that its going to replace all the pollEnrich patterns with the below mock url in that route. This should serve your purpose if you have only one pollEnrich within your route.

`weaveByType(PollEnrichDefinition.class).replace().to("mock:mock-url");`

You can also try setting an id for that particular pollEnrich like below in your route.

```
.pollEnrich("http4://localhost:8983/test", (exchange1, exchange2) -> {
                        return exchange1;
                    }).id("myPollEnrichId")
```

Once thats done, you can then use weavyById to mock that specific pollEnrich.

`weaveById("myPollEnrichId").replace().to("mock:mock-url");`

Comment: Thanks, but when I using `weaveByType` or `weabeById`  route doesn't call Aggregation strategy. Simply goes to the mock url and ignore  `(exchange1, exchange2) -> {
                        return exchange1;
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck with the problem that the replaced route does not call the aggregation strategy: You can use `weaveById` with `pollEnrich`, but you also need to add the AggregationStrategy parameter (see below), otherwise it won't call it, because it is replacing the original `pollEnrich` with a different one that doesn't have it.

First: Add an id to your original `pollEnrich` inside the `configure` method:

```
.pollEnrich("http4://localhost:8983/test", (exchange1, exchange2) -> {
                        return exchange1;
                    }).id("my-pollEnrich")
```

Second: In the tests, use `weaveById` to send it to a mock route with the aggregation strategy setted:

```
AdviceWithRouteBuilder mockHttp4 = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveById("my-pollEnrich").replace().pollEnrich("mock:my-pollEnrich-mock", (exchange1, exchange2) -> {
                return exchange1;
            }).id("my-pollEnrich"); //set the same id, otherwise it won't find when executing "beforeEach" again

        }
};
```

If you need to test the actual aggregation strategy in the route, the best way is to create a separated class for it and reuse it in the tests.